# Keras Model.load_weights doesn't work properly

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a keras model and I have saved its weights  after 10 epochs, with `loss: 103` and `accuracy: 0.80`.

But now when I'm loading the weights (as below) and calling `model.fit` the loss is 1357 and accuracy is 0.66 at the end of the first epoch

```
model.load_weights('path/to/weights.h5')
```

```py
history = model.fit(train_ds,
                    epochs=15,
                    initial_epoch=10)
```

Is there any way to load model weights in its previous state?

Comment: The code in your question does not load any weights.

Comment: It's added. @Dr.Snoopy

Comment: Do you re-compile the model? If so, it can be the optimizer, which is reset (internal variables).

Comment: Yes, I do. Is there any way to prevent this? However I wonder how it changes the loss and accuracy, could you explain please?! @elbe

Comment: Did you try running your code for the entire 15 epochs and check the loss and accuracy? Also, please provide minimal reproducible code to replicate the error if the issue still persists.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to load model weights in its previous state?

You can use Keras callbacks for achieving that.

From the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load) of Tensorflow, please refer to this section -

> The [tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/ModelCheckpoint) callback allows you to
> continually save the model both during and at the end of training.

You can use a callback that **saves weights only during training**

Using the model which you have already built, use :

```
checkpoint_path = "training_1/cp.ckpt"
checkpoint_dir = os.path.dirname(checkpoint_path)

# Create a callback that saves the model's weights
cp_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath=checkpoint_path,
                                                 save_weights_only=True,
                                                 verbose=1)

# Train the model with the new callback
model.fit(train_images, 
          train_labels,  
          epochs=10,
          validation_data=(test_images, test_labels),
          callbacks=[cp_callback])  # Pass callback to training
```